# NPOI set Explicit Column Type Not working properly

Tags: excel, npoi

I'm using NPOI Excel Library to generate a Excel file, in that Excel file i'm explicitly define column type for Columns like Date,String etc.

Im using the following code to achive this.

```
  var row = sheet.CreateRow(currentNPOIRowIndex++);
                    for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < exportData.Columns.Count; colIndex++)
                    {
                        ICell cell = null;
                         cell = row.CreateCell(colIndex);
                        if (exportData.Columns[colIndex].DataType == typeof(DateTime))
                        {
                            if (exportData.Rows[rowIndex][colIndex].ToString() != "")
                            {
                                cell.SetCellValue((DateTime)exportData.Rows[rowIndex][colIndex]);
                                cell.CellStyle = (NPOI.HSSF.UserModel.HSSFCellStyle)book.CreateCellStyle();
                                cell.CellStyle.DataFormat = book.CreateDataFormat().GetFormat("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss");
                                cell = null;
                            }
                            else
                                cell.SetCellValue(exportData.Rows[rowIndex][colIndex].ToString());
                        }
                        else
                            cell.SetCellValue(exportData.Rows[rowIndex][colIndex].ToString());
                    }
                }
```

The above code works fine for 42 rows i.e. it correctly set the Column Type,but after 42 rows Column Type doesn't apply.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: can you try the latest code. I  have provided you my workable solution. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you'll required to set default column style if you want to set column format for all cells of that column. Please see the below example from xssf format. Syntax may differ for your hssf format but it will give you idea what you are missing.

I am providing you from my working code. I am using NPOI version 2.2.1.0.
can you comment line  //cell = null;

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
  XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet)workbook.CreateSheet("Template");

  XSSFFont defaultFont = (XSSFFont)workbook.CreateFont();
  defaultFont.FontHeightInPoints = (short)10;

  XSSFCellStyle headerStyle = (XSSFCellStyle)workbook.CreateCellStyle();
  headerStyle.WrapText = true;

  XSSFCellStyle defaultStyle = (XSSFCellStyle)workbook.CreateCellStyle();
  XSSFDataFormat defaultDataFormat = (XSSFDataFormat)workbook.CreateDataFormat();
  defaultStyle.SetDataFormat(defaultDataFormat.GetFormat("000-000-0000"));
  defaultStyle.FillBackgroundColor = IndexedColors.LightYellow.Index;                
  defaultStyle.FillForegroundColor = IndexedColors.LightTurquoise.Index;
  defaultStyle.SetFont(defaultFont);

  var row = sheet.CreateRow(0);
  for (int headerCount = 0; headerCount < headers.Count(); headerCount++)
  {
      row.CreateCell(headerCount).SetCellValue(headers[headerCount]);
      row.Cells[headerCount].CellStyle = headerStyle;
      sheet.SetDefaultColumnStyle(headerCount, defaultStyle);          
  }
```

Comment: I tried your solution but still same problem exists, format apply till 42 rows.